# Kit specification item not link to Kit Specification Screen (ScreenId=IN209500)

Tags: acumatica

I've just created new report about Kit Specification List. That shows about kit specification item and components(Stock and Non-stock). In Report Designer on NavigateMethod=Server but in report view, click on kit specification item not link to Kit Specification Screen (ScreenId=IN209500)

[image]

[image]